# mysqli_query multiple query multiple connections

Tags: php, mysql

In the same script I'm executing 3 queries, and I'm always opening a connection:

```
//Second Query
 $con2= mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_pass,$db_name); 
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }
 $sql2= "INSERT INTO `documents` (doc_name,doc_type,doc_manager,doc_pointer) VALUES    ('$name', '$type', '$manager', '$pic')";
 if (!mysqli_query($con2,$sql2))
   {
   die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con2));
   }
 mysqli_close($con2);

 //Third query 
 $con3= mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_pass,$db_name); 
     if (mysqli_connect_errno())
         {
         echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
         }
     $sql3="UPDATE `thor(1.0)`.`documents` SET `doc_pointer` = '$Rigth_path' WHERE `documents`.`Protocol` ='$id'";
     if (!mysqli_query($con3,$sql3))
         {
         die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con3));
         }
     mysqli_close($con3);
```

(I did not publish the first query since it is too long).
I'm wondering if it is always necessary open and close a connection for each mysqli_query or could I use a single connection for all three connections?
In few word could I run the query `mysqli_query($con1,$sql3)`.

Comment: yes a single connection is sufficient

Comment: It's not only possible, it's quite good practice. (Re)connecting has overhead you don't need of want.

Comment: One connection should be sufficient(autocommit ON) unless you're making multiple transactions to support rollback, commit.